# vlc parameters to set audio stream from microphone

Tags: libvlc

I have C# project where stream from ip-camera recorded to the file, I use libvlc.

This is part of code with vlc parameters:

```
string VlcArguments = @":sout=#transcode{acodec=mpga,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=mp4,dst="C:\Users\I\Desktop\Output.mp4"}";

var media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>(rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov, VlcArguments);
var player = factory.CreatePlayer<IPlayer>();
player.Open(media);
```

`filename` is the path of the result file.
It works fine, but I need to record sound from a microphone ***Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)***. 
What I need to change to achieve that?

**UPD**
It should look something like this

```
var media = factory.CreateMedia<IMedia>("dshow:// dshow-vdev=rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov dshow-adev=Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)", VlcArguments)
```

But it doesn't work (

**UPD2**

So, I think I found the answer 
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=124229&p=425550&hilit=camera+microphone+dshow#p425550

Unfortunately this will not work

Comment: You should, at least, to post your code. Moreover did you meke any attempt?

Comment: I add code, Yes I was trying to substitute different parameters.. unsuccessfully